# CSS to change hyperlink colour on one page

Tags: css

I'm working on a WordPress site with the [Twenty Twenty theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwenty/) and have made some CSS changes which apply globally to make all hyperlinks red as below:

```
a {
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

I used the CSS customise side bar to globally change hyperlink colour to red but now I need to change the hyperlink colour to white for all 'list' links on just one page, leaving all other pages with red links (don't ask, it's a requirement of someone).

I have tried the CSS edits below and none seem to work for my page.  The hyperlinks are WordPress list items if it helps at all.  As you can probably tell I don't understand CSS enough to isolate one page to it's own styling.

```
.page-id-253:li{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```
.page-id-253:ul{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```
#page-id-253:link{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```
#page-id-253:a{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

How do I select the links in list items on just one page of my WordPress site?

Comment: Your CSS syntax is incorrect I’d suggest starting by reading e.g.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax.

And there is actually a :not selector in css where let you give style to the other element exclude the specific element.

```css
a{
color:red;
}  

/*a:not(#page-id-253 a){
color:red

}*/

.menuitem li a {
color:black

}
```

```html
<a >Click</a>
<ul class='menuitem'>
<li><a>Link </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@james Thanks a bunch, i had to make a small edit so the #page-id-253 to .page-id-253 and now the hyperlinks change to my chosen colour.

Only problem that has been introduced is my links list in the page footer have changed from black text to white also as the above is page wide.  Sorry I didn't probably ask my question enough the firs time around.

Now, do I need some kind of a subquery text change that would be along the lines (obviously wrong in my case!) like...

```
.page-id-253 a{
color:white;not(.footer-nav-widgets-wrapper)
}
```

```css
a{
color:red;
}  
#page-id-253 a{
color:black

}
```

```html
<a >Click</a>
<ul id='page-id-253'>
<li><a>Link </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I bit confused with your question. Could you be more descriptive?

Comment: @James , the code change is working for my hyperlink 'list items' on a wordpress page but since we changed the hyperlink (a) color across the whole page, it has inadvertently changed some links in my page footer (only on page-id-253) to white also. My next issue is working out how to change those back to black and leave the newly styled hyperlink on main page body links as white. 
The links in page footer when F12 inspected look like li#menu-item-65 (and other trailing numbers too)  I guess i could hard code the color for each menu item but thee are 12 of them and could be more in future.

Comment: Just update the code, check if it works!

Comment: Managed to fix this after all :o)

`li.menu-item a {
color: black;
}`

Comment: You should use `.menu-item li a` instead from the sequence of parent element to child element. Also, if you find my answer is helpful. Please accept it.

Comment: Wonder is my code solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to change the link color of just one page. So just add the `style` tag to that page.

```html
<head> <!-- the page you want to change link color -->

<!-- add this tag to your page -->
<style>

  li a {
    color: #000;
  }

</style>
<!-- end -->

</head>
```